# A lemma is John Lee's Riemannian Manifold having problem with proving it

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

The tangential connection on an embedded submanifold $M ⊂ R^n$ is symmetric.

the hint is let $X,Y$ be vector fields that are tangent of M at points of M, so is $[X,Y]$

I start with $$T(X,Y)=\nabla_x Y-\nabla_yX-[X,Y]$$ and thinking prove first part of equation would equal to the second part of equation ..

not sure if it's right or not

Comment: what is the definition of a tangential connection?

Comment: http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/leeriemm.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. The tangential connection is nothing but the Levi-Civita connection for the induced metric. So it is symmetric. Besides this fact we can calculate it directly:
Let D be the tangential connection, $\bar{D}$ be the connection of the ambient Euclidean space, and P be the projection operator then $D=P(\bar{D})$, and
$$ D_X(Y)-D_Y(X)=P(\bar{D}_X(Y))-P(\bar{D}_Y(X))=P(\bar{D}_X(Y)-\bar{D}_Y(X))=P([X,Y])=[X,Y]$$